# method range in class Car cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, methods

the error is in the CarUser class, required: double; found: no arguments; reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length.

i do not understand how to return a range method from this code i made. i have the psuedocode for it, but i do not know how to turn it into a legit code. Also, can someone double check my other methods as well?

```
    /**
    * Class to determine Car's range of miles. 
    * 
    * @author Kelvynn Cayanan 
    * @version 2/2/2014
    */
    public class Car
    {
        // instance variables - 
        private double miles;
        private double gallons;
        private double gas;

        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class Car
         */
        public Car()
        {

        }
        public Car(double initialGas)
        {
            gas = initialGas;
        }

        public void addGas(double gas)
        {
            // Increases amount of gas in gas tank.
            gallons = gallons + gas;
        }

        public void drive(double drive)
        {
            // Decreases amount of gas in gas tank.
            double newdrive = (drive/miles) - gas;
            drive = newdrive;
        }

        public double range(double range)
        {
            //**calculates range, the number of miles the car can travel until the gas tank is empty       */
            double newrange = miles * gas;
            range = newrange;
            return range;
        }
    }
```

here is a class that i am supposed to implement with the class i made above.

```
    /**
    * Uses Cars.
    * 
    * @author Anthony W. Smith 
    * @version 6/15/2009
    */
    public class CarUser
    {
        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class CarUser
         */
        public CarUser()
        {
            Car honda = new Car(30.0); // 30 miles per gallon

            honda.addGas(9.0); // add 9 more gallons
            honda.drive(210.0); // drive 210 miles

            // print range remaining
            System.out.println("Honda range remaining: " + honda.range());

            Car toyota = new Car(26.0); // 26 miles per gallon

            toyota.addGas(4.5); // add 4.5 more gallons
            toyota.drive(150.0); // drive 150 miles

            // print range remaining
            System.out.println("Toyota range remaining: " + toyota.range());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just as a tip `public double range(double range)` having a method and a variable with the same name could be confusing. You should consider changing one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You're over-complicating things. Change the range method definition in the Car class, as it shouldn't have a parameter. Its signature and body should be nothing but:

```
public double range() {
  return miles * gas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What Hovercraft Full of Eels wrote was correct to a certain extent.

Here are some tips that I think will help you out in your planning process.

---

**First Tip:**

Think of your **CarUser** class as your guide towards creating an algorithm for the **Car** class.

You can think of an algorithm as a basic formula that your machine applies to specific input values in order to "Do something".

As an example:`public double range()` is a method whose job is to return a value back to the user. What does the user want returned regarding range? Is it range in **gallons of gasoline** or is it in **miles**?
(Hint: the one that requires less thinking)

First write on a piece of paper the information **CarUser** gives you using honda or toyota:

> (Honda)**Miles Per Gallon**: 30.0
>     **Starting Gas in Tank**: 3.5 Gal
>     **Amount of Gas Added**: 9.0 Gal
>     **Total Gas After Added**: 12.5 Gal

There needs to be some type of formula we can apply in order to find this **"Range"**...it involves a little bit of multiplication and subtraction..

---

**Another Tip that will help you out**: Compile and Run each method in your new **Car** class in BlueJ before moving on to the next method. If you run **Car** by itself, it should probably prompt you to enter a **Value** which you can then **Inspect** (to see if the program is responding how you'd like it to).

---

**A Third Tip**: After compiling your **Car** class, try compiling your **CarUser** class and
BlueJ should point out your problems.

---

**A Final Tip**: **YOUR VARIABLE NAMES AND METHODS SHOULD HAVE CLEAR & MEANINGFUL NAMES AND INCLUDED COMMENTS** so when another programmer is looking at your work, they can tell what each method and variable is and does. That is one of the few reasons why ***addGas*** is used instead of ***aG***.

Good Luck!